# How do I specify a label/path with special characters as 'ñ' in /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

I know that if a path has spaces one can encode it with **\040**:

Example for path:

> "//server/folder with spaces"

fstab entry:

```
//server/folder\040with\040spaces /mnt/share/folder_local cifs nofail,credentials=/root/.credfile 0 0
```

But how to fill fstab if you have a path with non-English chars as **'ñ'**?

Path example:

> "//server/folderWith-ñ-char"

I've tried:

fstab entry:

```
//server/folderWith-\F1-char /mnt/share/folder_local cifs nofail,credentials=/root/.credfile 0 0
```

based on:
https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

but I get the error:

```
 mount -a
mount error(2): No such file or directory
```

Comment: Just type `//server/folderWith-ñ-char`. `ith-\F1-char` why `\F1`?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! Sorry for the inconvenience, my VIM editor marked that char in red and I thought that was an error. If you formally answer the question I will marked it as solved. Best regards.

Comment: `F1` is hex.  Here you need octal, namely `\0361`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type `//server/folderWith-ñ-char`, `ñ` is not anyhow special.

In case of problems, you can use `mnt_mangle` from linux-util. Compile this short program:

```
$ printf "%s\n" '#include "libmount/libmount.h"' 'int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { puts(mnt_mangle(argv[1])); }' | gcc -xc - -lmount -o mnt_mangle
```

Then you can use:

```
$ ./mnt_mangle '//server/folderWith-ñ-char'
//server/folderWith-ñ-char
```

Comment: Hi, do you have some documentation on this `mnt_mangle()` function ?

Comment: https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/libmount/src/utils.c#LL269C4-L269C4